# cx_oracle unexpected timestamp behavour

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've been experiencing some strange behavior with cx_oracle. i have procedure in a package that updates a table using a merge statement.  the procedure takes in a 8 arrays of values, all NUMBER with one VARCHAR2 and one TIMESTAMP to be updated. the timestamps being sent are hardcoded  as `datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 13, 20, 10)` so the expected timestamp value should be `2017-10-09 13:20:10:000000` when i run the script from my windows machine on both my dev database and production,  the timestamp entered is correct. however when i run it from my linux host (centos) the time stamp is only entered correctly on the dev database and on the production DB the timestamp is `2017-10-09 13:20:10:005400` with the ms/us being random and changing every run.

Initially I would think this to be a client configuration issue, however as it works from the same client on one db and not on the other, and from the other windows client works on both it is a bit more confusing, the NLS settings on both clients are the same.

**Python code**

```
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
import numpy as np


id_list = ['XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXX', 'XXXX']
time_list = [datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 13, 20, 10),
             datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 13, 20, 21),
             datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 13, 11, 17),
             datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 13, 10, 1),
             datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 12, 7, 10),
             ]

bid_list = [32.09, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ask_list = [33.789, 0, 0, 0, 0]
t_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
f_m = [20, 0, 0, 0, 0]
rfv_list = [256, 45, 9, 0, 0]
fv = [10, 134, 46.0, 0, 0]


db = cx_Oracle.connect('/@wallet_user')
cursor = db.cursor()

string_arr = lambda cur, array: cur.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.STRING, array)
time_arr = lambda cur, array: cur.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP, array)
number_arr = lambda cur, array: cur.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, array)

p_id = string_arr(cursor, id_list)
p_time = time_arr(cursor, time_list)
p_bid = number_arr(cursor, bid_list)
p_ask = number_arr(cursor, ask_list)
p_t = number_arr(cursor, t_list)
p_futures = number_arr(cursor, f_m)
p_rfv = number_arr(cursor, rfv_list)
p_fv = number_arr(cursor, fv)

cursor.callproc('PKG_TEST.prc_load_test_values', [p_id, p_time, p_bid, p_ask, p_t, p_futures, p_rfv, p_fv])
db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

**PL/sql procedure**

```
PROCEDURE prc_load_load_test_values ( p_id IN aa_iepnfv_id,
                                     p_tof IN aa_tof,
                                     p_r_bid IN aa_iepnfv_r_bid,
                                     p_r_ask IN aa_iepnfv_r_ask,
                                     p_r_t IN aa_iepnfv_r_t,
                                     p_r_fm IN aa_iepnfv_r_fm,
                                     p_r_fv IN aa_iepnfv_r_fv,
                                     p_fv IN aa_iepnfv_fv
                                     )
IS
l_error_count PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN
    DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('TRUNCATE TABLE tablename');
    FORALL i IN p_id.FIRST .. p_id.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        INSERT INTO IRE_ETF_PRICING_NET_FAIR_VALUE
        (
            id,
            tof,
            r_bid,
            r_ask,
            r_t,
            r_fm,
            r_fv,
            fv
        )
        VALUES
        (
            p_id(i),
            p_tof(i),
            p_r_bid(i),
            p_r_ask(i),
            p_r_t(i),
            p_r_fm(i),
            p_r_fv(i),
            p_fv(i)
        );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows inserted '||SQL%ROWCOUNT);

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN array_dml_exception THEN
            l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
            FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error bulk load at index '|| SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX||' for error message '||
                                SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);

            END LOOP;

END prc_load_load_test_values;
```

Comment: Weird. What does your `aa_tof` type look like? And what type is the column `IRE_ETF_PRICING_NET_FAIR_VALUE.tof`?

Comment: aa_tof is  
TYPE aa_tof IS TABLE OF tablename.tof%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

where the column tablename.tof is `TIMESTAMP(6)` .

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle are you using? There was one issue in a release candidate that may be similar to what you are seeing.

Comment: the cx_Oracel version is 5.1.2 on python 2.7.